# React+Typescript declare type before component vs after component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am new to typescript, I saw some projects declaring the type before component and some of them declare after the component, may I know what are the differences?

```
export type TProps = {
    item: string;
}
export default function Component({item}: TProps) {
}
```

vs

```
export default function Component({item}: TProps) {
}

export type TProps = {
    item: string;
}
```

both of the code are able to run, which one is better and why?

couldn't find any article about this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same thing just like in `JavaScript` we can call function before initialisation.

It's just depends on developer who he can write the `types` .

Answer (score 1):

When using types for props specifically, I tend to put it before the component. I do this for readability so I can quickly see what the component takes for parameters.

Ultimately it comes down to preference, but for readability sake, I like to keep it at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I like types above or in a separate file and maybe interface but in your case, something like this:

```
type TProps = {
  item?: string;
};

const Component = ({ item = 'Test' }: TProps) => <div>{item}</div>;

export default Component;
// ...
<Parent>
<Component /> {/* skipping prop will default in 'Test' */}
</Parent>
```

Also I really like how compact and neat arrow functions for components are! (no FC required nowadays because `defaultProps` can be done through default param values of the props).